# Login and Accessing the twitter tweets in Django application creating issues

Tags: python, django, twitter

For integrating my application with tweeter to access the tweets, I have followed this blog: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/10/24/how-to-add-social-login-to-django.html

I think I have integrated the application but here the error that I am getting:

```
 NoReverseMatch at /oauth/complete/twitter/
Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://52.66.181.149:2000/oauth/complete/twitter/?redirect_state=X0zmjSh0yJi6eGwwfXvxXNmKKEwoouLc&oauth_token=tSrVkgAAAAAA2fYTAAABXuuIht0&oauth_verifier=sZg5nxlmdbqDBTlnuDLtmCOWxFKDnyVH
Django Version: 1.11.5
Exception Type: NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    
Reverse for 'home' not found. 'home' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 497
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.12
Python Path:    
['/home/ubuntu/Personality',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages']
    Server time:    My time
```

The complete trace back is here : [Trace Back Gist](https://gist.github.com/JafferWilson/6a91fecac35cadff52cc4d5e204f3d2b)

Also, I would like to know the following 2 things:
1) What is missing which is causing this issue?
2) What I can do to collect the tweets with django and use it as NLP data set?

Kindly, let me know.

This is how I am calling it:

```
<form method="post" action="/fileprocess/" enctype="multipart/form-data"  class="box has-advanced-upload" id="sendfile">

<div id = "loginBtn" class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true" onlogin = "javascript:login()"></div>


<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'twitter' %}">Login with Twitter</a>
```

Comment: Your error is quite clearly not related to collecting tweets. You should choose a more appropriate title for your question, and also search for the many, many previous questions on the error you are actually getting.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is happened because there is NO url pattern which has 'home' as name. so change this:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'home'
```

to

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

(in your `settings.py`)

Second question is not relevent with this issue, but how about look at this?:

http://www.kdnuggets.com/2014/10/tweetnlp-twitter-natural-language-processing.html

Comment: Thank you.... this helped. The link is not the answer to my question. I mean that I just need to get the access to tweets of the person who login with oauth application. I hope you got my point.